# For bash scripting

Tags: bash, scripting

```
#!/bin/bash
read –p “Enter the number you seek   ” NUM
for VALUE in $@; do
    if [ $VALUE –eq $NUM ]; then COUNT=$((COUNT+1)); fi
done
echo $NUM appeared $COUNT times
```

Can the above script be modified so that :
 input two inputs from the user, instead of just NUM, and count the number of parameters that are equal to or in between the two.  For instance, if the user inputs 12 and 20, we would have 5 matches (12, 18, 19, 12, 18).  Assume the first input is less than the second (that is, you do not need to worry about the user inputting 20 and then 12)

This is what i am coming up with:

```
#1/bin/bash
read - p "Enter two numbers ' NUM1 NUM2 
for VALUE in $@; do 
if [$VALUE <= $NUM1 ] && [ $VALUE => $NUM2 ]; then COUNT=$((COUNT+1))
fi 
done
echo we have $COUNT numbers between $NUM1 and $NUM2, including $NUM1 and $NUM2
```

Comment: Don't use curly quotes in code. Turn off "Smart Quotes" in your editor.

Comment: `read -p "Enter two numbers" num1 num2`

Comment: What problem are you having modifying the script to do that?

Comment: Please put the code in the question so you can format it readably. But the main problem is that you have to use `-ge` and `-le`, not `>=` and `<=`. And your conditions are backwards, the value should be greater than num1 and less than num2 if it's supposed to be between them.

Comment: Stop using uppercase variable names, by convention those are for environment variables.

Comment: will do. I will make the modifications

Comment: it is working fine now. i appreciate you!

Answer (score 0):

1. `#1` is a typo for `#!`.
2. You need a space after `[`.
3. Your conditions are backwards. When value is between num1 and num2, it's greater than or equal to num1, but you have less than or equal.
4. The numeric comparison tests are `-ge` and `-le`, since `>` and `<` are I/O redirection operators in shell scripts.
5. You have to use balanced quotes around a string; if it starts with `"` it has to end with `"`, not `'`.
6. You should always quote variables unless you have a specific need to allow word splitting of the expansion.

```
#!/bin/bash
COUNT=0
read - p "Enter two numbers " NUM1 NUM2 
for VALUE in "$@"; do 
if [ "$VALUE" -ge "$NUM1" ] && [ "$VALUE" -le "$NUM2" ]; then COUNT=$((COUNT+1))
fi 
done
echo "we have $COUNT numbers between $NUM1 and $NUM2, including $NUM1 and $NUM2"
```